# django models many-to-many relations issue

Tags: django, models

Django 1.3.

Suppose I have models:

```
class Inspector(models.Model):
    field = models.IntegerField()

Model_1(models.Model):
    inspectors = ManyToManyField(InspectorData)
```

And I have to create another model, where a field can store data only from `Model_1().inspectors` attribute. Smth like:

```
class Model_2(models.Model):
    model_1_inspectors = ManyToManyField(Model_1__inspectors)
```

How can I accomplish this in Django (if it is possible)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have created the model in the question itself. What else do you want?

Comment: I am no sure that `ManyToManyField(Model_1__inspectors)` does work in django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is to override `save` method in `Model_1` and on every save operation update inspectors in specially created model `Model1inspectors`. This way `Model_2' will look just like yours from question.

But i think it's better to customize queryset for that `ManyToManyField` in your **form** like this:

```
class Model_2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model_2Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['model_1_inspectors'].queryset = InspectorData.objects.filter(
            pk__in=Model_1.objects.values('inspectors').distinct())
```

Answer (score 0):

import the model required as

```
from myapp_folder.models import Inspector
class Model_2(models.Model):
    model_1_inspectors = ManyToManyField(Inspector)
```

This will work